# Memory leak in debug mode only

Tags: c#, json.net, dotnetzip

I have this code:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
    {
        var list = new List<Actor>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Actor("lorem ipsum"));
        }

        using (var serializedContent = new MemoryStream())
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list));
            streamWriter.Flush();
            serializedContent.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                zip.AddEntry("message.txt", serializedContent);
                zip.Save("Archive.zip");
            }
        }
    }
}

while (true)
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
    GC.Collect();
    Console.WriteLine("completed");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The problem is that a memory leak only appears in debug version, while in release it fully cleans after itself. Any ideas why could this be happening?

**Edit.**
I noticed that the problem disappears if I remove that part where I try to add files to zip archive. What could be the difference between debug and release versions with this code? I can't see the problem, because archiving part is executed within the `using` statement.

Comment: What is the implementation of actor? What exactly is leaking? Did you profile it?

Comment: Actor class has one string variable that holds its name, nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your code into a function.

Take a look at [this blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yunjin/2005/05/15/figure-out-variable-lifetime-using-sos/):

> The tricky point is that a variable is eligible to be dead once it’s
>   not used anymore. However, it’s up to JIT to determine whether it
>   really wants to report the variable to be dead. In fact, for
>   debuggable code, JIT extends lifetime for every variable to end of the
>   function.

This means your variable will not be collected, by `GC.Collect`, because your variable is in the same function and at debugtime still in scope.

Remember: The garbage collector only removes variable that are not used (not in scope). `using` is only calling `Dispose` on an object.

Comment: At first it didn't work, but then I realized that I wrapped my code into a static method. Thanks!

Comment: The annoying thing is that these zombie-variables don't appear in a memory snapshot because they supposed to be dead, by they still alive in the memory. And wrapping the code into function solved the problem. Thanks!